# Django-Template : Get Variables in a Tag block !

Tags: django, templates, django-templates

I need to retrieve an optional number saved in DB , to a custom template tag i made . which to retrieve , a variable ( a photo ID ) included in this Gallery . within the gallery loop .

```
{% get_latest_photo   {{photo.id}}  %}
```

How to accomplish that ?!

P.s : I know that can be done with inclusion tag , but in the present time how to make it fix this one !

Edit the template html file :

```
{% for album in albumslist %}

    {% get_latest_photo   photo.id  %} 
    {% for photo in recent_photos %}
<img src='{% thumbnail photo.image 200x80 crop,upscale %}' alt='{{ photo.title }}' />
    {% endfor %}
    {{ album.title }}
{% endfor %}
```

templatetag

```
from django.template import Library, Node
from akari.main.models import *
from django.db.models import get_model

register = Library()

class LatestPhotoNode(Node):
    def __init__(self, num):
        self.num = num
    def render(self, context):
        photo = Photo.objects.filter(akar=self.num)[:1]
        context['recent_photos'] = photo
        return ''

def get_latest_photo(parser, token):
    bits = token.contents.split()
    return LatestPhotoNode(bits[1])

get_latest_photo = register.tag(get_latest_photo)
```

P.s Its working very well when i replace album.id (in {% get_latest_photo   photo.id  %} ) with a number which acts as an album id and retrieve the photo from .

Regards
H. M.

Comment: If you tell us how the code misbehaves, it will be easier for us to give you answers.

Comment: Can you post the code of the tag?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To evaluate correctly the **num** variable I think you should modify your **LatestPhotoNode** class like this:

```
class LatestPhotoNode(Node):
    def __init__(self, num):
        self.num = template.Variable(num)

    def render(self, context):
        num = self.variable.resolve(self.num)
        photo = Photo.objects.filter(akar=num)[:1]
        context['recent_photos'] = photo
        return ''
```

Comment: How do you make it work with filtered value? like in `{% url_parameter tags=tag|slugify %}`

Comment: What is `self.variable` ?

Answer (score 8):

You don't put the brackets around variables when you use them in template tags.

```
{% get_latest_photo photo.id %}
```

Comment: tried that before i add the brackets but didn't work at all !

Answer (score 3):

Are you sure your template tag is written properly?  For example, you need to use Variable.resolve to properly get the values of variables: [Passing Template Variables to the Tag](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/#passing-template-variables-to-the-tag)

Comment: Hello Ned , 
How to use Variable.resolve , am searching about that now , can you link me an example please ?!

Comment: Just  a classic custom template tag which will filter the photos and get the latest photo added with this album . i Edited the main Question .

Comment: Hmm ,
WIll do soon , but somehow i believe the Custom Template tag is not the problem , cause it works very fine when i replace the photo.id with a number with filter the Photo with the album.id !

Comment: Hello Ned , i fixed it using this http://codespatter.com/2009/01/22/how-to-write-django-template-tags/ .

Thank You

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem problem and after [reading the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/howto/custom-template-tags/#registering-the-tag), I solved it using this

```
class LatestPhotoNode(Node):
    def __init__(self, num):
        self.num = template.Variable(num)

    def render(self, context):
        num = self.num.resolve(context)
        photo = Photo.objects.filter(akar=num)[:1]
        context['recent_photos'] = photo
        return ''
```

If you are trying to render multiple variables, using `json.dumps` is very useful.