# My custom template tag in Django rendering template variables as string

Tags: django, django-templates

Usage of tag -

`{% for x in posts %}

{% render_con_form for shastra x.id %}`

Instead of passing the value of x.id which would be an integer it passes - 'x.id' as it is.
How can I fix this ?

Edit -

```
def render(self, context):
    if self.app == 'broadcast' or self.app == 'shastra':
        form = CommentsForm()   
    str = render_to_string('comments/form.html', {'form' : form, 'app' : self.app, 'id' : self.id})
    return str
```

`def __init__(self, app, id):

             self.app = str(app)

             self.id = Variable(id)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to use the solution of the accepted answer below:

[Django-Template : Get Variables in a Tag block !](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1269280/django-template-get-variables-in-a-tag-block)

Inside your template tag

```
// obj is x.id
def __init__(self, obj):
    from django.template import Variable
    // get the variable value
    self.id = Variable(obj)

def render(self, context):
    id = self.id.resolve(context)
```

Comment: Hey look at my edit, it still doesn't work, do I have to do something in the render function as well ?

Comment: Caught VariableDoesNotExist while rendering: Failed lookup for key [x] in u'x.id' - this is the error

Comment: Hey now on submitting my form I'm getting a CSRF error, it seems the custom tag's context is overriding the main page's context.

Comment: this shouldn't be related, inside the template tag you'll have to resolve the context variable 'csrf_token' using Variable.resolve() and then include an <input type="hidden"> with its value..