# Pass variables as arguments to Django custom tag in view

Tags: python, html, django, templatetags, django-custom-tags

I have a custom tag in Django project:

```py
class ExampleNode(template.Node):
    def __init__(self,
                 nodelist,
                 header_copy='',
                 paragraph_copy='',
                 ):
        self.nodelist = nodelist
        self.header_copy = header_copy
        self.paragraph_copy = paragraph_copy

    def render(self, context):
        template = 'example.html'
        context = {
            'elements': self.nodelist.render(context),
            "header_copy": self.header_copy,
            "paragraph_copy": self.paragraph_copy,
        }
        return render_to_string(template, context)

@register.tag
def example_component(parser, token):
    try:
        tag_name, header_copy, paragraph_copy = token.split_contents()
    except ValueError:
        raise TemplateSyntaxError("%r takes two arguments" % token.contents.split()[0])
    nodelist = parser.parse(('endexample_component',))
    parser.delete_first_token()
    return ExampleNode(nodelist, header_copy, paragraph_copy)
```

And the view of the component is:

```html
  <div>
     <h1>{{ header_copy }}</h1>
     <p>{{ paragraph_copy }}</p>
  </div>
  <div>{{ elements }}</div>
```

Usage:

```html
{% with header_copy='Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet' paragraph_copy='Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus.' %}
      {% example_component header_copy paragraph_copy %}
          <div>ex1</div>
          <div>ex2</div>
      {% endexample_component %}
{% endwith %}
```

And the issue is that what I am receiving in view is `header_copy` and `paragraph_copy` instead of `Lorem ipsum`. Only passing actual primitive value works.

Maybe there is a better way to receive those args and parse them?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Django-Template : Get Variables in a Tag block !](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1269280/django-template-get-variables-in-a-tag-block)